# Configure reinforced typings to export one type to multiple target directory

Tags: reinforced-typings

I'm using fluent configuration to export my c# DTOs to typescript classes. I have two web projects and I would like to export my DTOs to both projects.

ConfigurationBuilder has extension method ExportAsClasses but it allows to specify target file name only once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, RT does not support such functionality. But you can set up [post-build event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-specify-build-events-csharp?view=vs-2019) for your project that will copy generated files wherever you need.